# Passing a string value to a different view controller through tables accessory button

Tags: ios, string, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am aware there are similar threads, I have searched a lot on the web and I have tried a lot of things but I still cannot make it work. I am trying to pass the value of a string from one view controller to another one, when the user clickes on the accessory button of a UITableView. The transition works properly but in the destination view controller the strings prints null. I know it is a common procedure.. but nothing seems to work. I have tried mutable strings, copy, retain, strong, creating an instance to destination and source controllers. Please if someone can provide me a solution I would really be grateful.

**SourceViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString*reference; // I have tried retain, copy, nsmutablestring also
```

**SourceViewController.m**

```
#import "DestinationViewController.h"


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        self.reference = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[allreferences objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] - 1]];

        NSLog(@"%@", self.reference); // it prints the value correctly

        DestinationViewController * destinationViewController = [[DestinationViewController alloc] init];

        destinationViewController.reference = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.reference];


        NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
        UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destination"];
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];


    }
```

**DestinationViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString * reference; // i have tried strong, copy, nsstring also
```

**DestinationViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"%@", self.reference); // it prints null

    self.sourcevalue.text = self.reference;  // assigning the value to a label


}
```

**ANSWER:**

Finally fixed it. The problem was my transition.

I changed:

```
DestinationViewController * destinationViewController = [[DestinationViewController alloc] init];
```

to:

```
DestinationViewController * destinationViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destination"];
```

Also changed the transition to:

```
 [self presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the string into a viewcontroller and presenting another one.

In your storyboard did you set the class of the viewcontroller to be "DestinationViewController"?

Try something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        self.reference = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[allreferences objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] - 1]];

        NSLog(@"%@", self.reference); // it prints the value correctly

/* This is wrong!
            DestinationViewController * destinationViewController = [[DestinationViewController alloc] init];

            destinationViewController.reference = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.reference];
*/
        NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
        UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destination"];
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        // Cast vc to the real class
        DestinationViewController * destinationViewController = (DestinationViewController*)vc;
        destinationViewController.reference = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.reference];

       [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

I didn't change all the code so if you paste this it should work, but i suggest you put back your property to strong and NSString.